# Running dist-upgrade fails on installation of 'startpar'

Tags: debian, apt, upgrade

I'm trying to run `dist-upgrade` on Debian 6 but it fails on installation of `startpar` with:

```
dpkg: considering deconfiguration of sysvinit-utils, which would be broken by installation of startpar ...
dpkg: no, sysvinit-utils is essential, will not deconfigure
it in order to enable installation of startpar.
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/startpar_0.59-3_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 installing startpar would break existing software
configured to not write apport reports
                                  Processing triggers for man-db ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/startpar_0.59-3_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Do you have any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Startpar is not included in Debian 6, so you've obviously mucked about with your repository config. Undo that, remove startpar and try again.